# Angle Addition Identities Trignometry

Tags: trigonometry

I'm working on a problem with angle addition, using the trig identities and seem to have gotten stuck. See screenshot for the work I have done in the red area. Any assistance is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Assuming your other work is right, you could write $\sqrt{12}=2\sqrt{3}$ and then cancel a 2 in numerator and denominator.

Comment: Thank you. That's what got me to the correct answer, an you add it as an answer so I can accept it? Appreciate it.

Comment: Nah, I'll just keep it as a comment.  Cheers.

Comment: Why don't you use $\tan 45^\circ = 1$...? This would give $(1+\sqrt 3)/(\sqrt 3 - 1)$ as soon as in the second step...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your work up to the last step is fine.  (Yes, you could have said $\tan 45^\circ = 1$ but 
$\sqrt{2}/\sqrt{2}$ is surely OK.)

After your last step, I would rationalize the denominator as follows:
$$
\frac{6+\sqrt{12}}{6-\sqrt{12}} = \frac{6+\sqrt{12}}{6+\sqrt{12}} \cdot \frac{6+\sqrt{12}}{6-\sqrt{12}} = \frac{36+12\sqrt{12}+12}{6^2-12}= \frac{48+12\sqrt{12}}{24} = 2+\frac{\sqrt{12}}{2} = 2+\sqrt{3}
$$